# Scripting with Jquery Mobile takes effect only after refresh

Tags: jquery, mobile, refresh

I have this little script that i run under "HEAD" tag, working with jquery mobile. It resizes images according to screen width. It works fine, but it only works after a refresh on that page every time. Is there anyway i can force to refresh every time you enter a page? Or is there a better method of doing this?

The script goes like this:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function()
  {
     $width = $( '#content' ).width();
     $( '#content img' ).css( 
     {
        'max-width': $width, 'height': 'auto'
     } );
   } );
</script>
```

Thanks

-----UPDATED------

```
<body>
  <script>
    $( document ).live( 'pageload', function()
    {
      var maxWidth = $( '.content' ).width();
      $( '.content img' ).css( "max-width", maxWidth );
      $( '.content img' ).css( "height", auto );
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't put your javascript/jquery code in the HEAD section, make sure it's in the BODY because jquery mobile filters out code in there. Jquery mobile only uses the TITLE from the HEAD.

Use something like this:

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function() {
    // make sure all submit buttons are disabled to being with
    $('input#submit').each(function() {
        $(this).button("disable");
    });
});
```

I know this example isn't the functionality you're looking for, but the concept is the same. Bind your event to "pagecreate" like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the AJAX page loading of JQM? If you are, you should bind to the `pageload` event. All the events are described here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. In the `pageload` event handler you can add your code to resize the images.

You could also bind to the `pageshow` event for each page.

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function () {
//Image resize code here
```

});

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the advice. I did updated the code with the pageload event. But i seem to be getting the same result. The images are being resized after the page is fully loaded, but it doesn't show it until another event happens (ie. you go to another page ). I've been fiddling around with the event triggers, but nothing seems to be working. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Added another option to the answer

Comment: Tried that too, but $width seems to be getting 0 all the time. I think it's because at the time page loaded, all elements including div are hidden. Is there anyway i can find out the width() of a hidden element?